# Entity Framework hides n to n table

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, visual-studio, entity-framework

I have the following tables created using SQL Server management studio (I must not let EF create the DB because I need customized indexing along with something else).

Table A (AId)
Table B (BId)
Table AB(AId, BId)

There are foreign key constrains setup so A - B is a n-n relationship.

Now, when I import the model into EF, the relationship is displayed as * - * (which is correct), but Table AB is gone. This is not what I want! I want to have the ability to manually manage the relationship. How can I have EF show this table?

(the reason is the way EF manage relationship through strongly typed objects is counter performance - e.g. I want to manually create a B and link it to some As (I know the ID) without selecting those As and adding it in B's collection)

Comment: Have you considered code-first?

Comment: I have to customize the DB with index, sequences etc. In short I want full control of my tables, I don't want EF to create them for me.

Comment: [You can use code-first with an existing database](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj200620.aspx).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Slauma stated it is possible to add a dummy field, but more importantly you can remove that dummy field and still have the link table.

Simple create the table AB, with an extra column called "Dummy" for example. Generate your model from this table. The table will now be included in the model.

Now got to the database and drop the "Dummy" column.

You can now either refresh the model from the database of simple delete the mapping for the "Dummy" column. You now have the link table in your EF model.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to force EF to expose the link table as an entity when you create the model via database first - unless you change the schema in a way that EF does not consider the table as a pure many-to-many link table anymore, for example by adding a "dummy column" to the table. When you are using Code-First however, you can manually create an entity for the link table with two one-to-many relationships between `A` and `AB` and between `B` and `AB`.

I am not convinced by your argument why you want to do that...

> I want to manually create a B and link it to some As (I know the ID)
>   without selecting those As and adding it in B's collection.

...because you don't need to load any entities from the database if you know the key values. You can use attached stub entities in order to create the relationships and write entries into the link table:

```cs
var newB = new B { As = new List<A>() };
foreach (var aId in someAIdCollection)
{
    var existingA = new A { Id = aId };
    context.As.Attach(existingA);
    newB.As.Add(existingA);
}
context.Bs.Add(newB);
context.SaveChanges();
```

No database query is involved here and the resulting SQL commands are the same like inserting an `AB` link entity directly.